# How to remove duplicate values in a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to remove duplicate values inside a dictionary.

Let's say this is my dictionary:

```
dict = {'X' : 
[
 {id : 1, Name: 'RandomName', Brand: 'RandomBrand'}, 
 {id: 2, Name: 'RandomName2', Brand: 'RandomBrand2'}
],
'Y': 
[
 {id: 1, Name: 'RandomName', Brand: 'RandomBrand'},
 {id: 1, Name: 'RandomName', Brand: 'RandomBrand'}
]
}
```

I want to have this as end-result after removing the duplicates

**RESULT:**

```
dict = {'X' : 
[
 {id : 1, Name: 'RandomName', Brand: 'RandomBrand'}, 
 {id: 2, Name: 'RandomName2', Brand: 'RandomBrand2'}
],
'Y': 
[
 {id: 1, Name: 'RandomName', Brand: 'RandomBrand'}
]
}
```

How would I do this?

Comment: You are not removing duplicates from a dictionary. You have *lists* with duplicates, and those duplicates happen to be dictionaries. That your lists are themselves contained in a dictionary is not really that relevant to the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Dictionaries by default don't accept duplicates. Look closely, you have `dict[str:list[dict[...]]` there. So you want to filter duplicated dictionaries from list.

**Answer:**
If order doesn't matter, and you want to remove only exact duplicates, just go this way:

```
structure = ... # your `dict` - you shouldn't use keyword as a variable name.
structure = {key: list(frozenset(tuple(d.items()) for d in value)) for key, value in st.items()}
```

If order matters, replace 'list' with 'sorted' and define key to sort it right.

@Edit: If performance is also a thing, you shouldn't take that task yet, you're lack of basics, and introducing proper structure is kind of overkill.

In case of any nested 'list_comprehension', I would highly discourage that, as it'll most likely perform even more poorly than my example.

@Edit2:
Of course, if you want reverse it to proper structure, you can play with that further.

@Edit3:
[example execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAthk.png)

Comment: Your answer doesn't work, You can't use `set` on a list of dictionaries. `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`

Comment: key is also undefined in pylance.

Comment: Ah, you're right, I should just use frozenset there :)

Comment: And yea, tuple of items seems to be obligatory in python3.5+

Comment: @Guaz when I try this I get an 'unhashable type: dict' error.

Comment: Idk, works for me, check edit3 image

Answer (score 1):

Try with dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> {k: [dict(t) for t in {tuple(d.items()) for d in v}] for k,v in dct.items()}
{'X': [{'id': 2, 'Name': 'RandomName2', 'Brand': 'RandomBrand2'},
       {'id': 1, 'Name': 'RandomName', 'Brand': 'RandomBrand'}],
 'Y': [{'id': 1, 'Name': 'RandomName', 'Brand': 'RandomBrand'}]}
```

###### Input:

```
dct = {'X': [{"id": 1, "Name": 'RandomName', "Brand": 'RandomBrand'}, 
             {"id": 2, "Name": 'RandomName2', "Brand": 'RandomBrand2'}],
       'Y': [{"id": 1, "Name": 'RandomName', "Brand": 'RandomBrand'},
             {"id": 1, "Name": 'RandomName', "Brand": 'RandomBrand'}]}
```

Comment: This gives an unhashable type: 'list' error.

Comment: Not sure how you get that. It works on the sample you provided.